# How to set null value using config map in spring boot applicaton

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

I follow [this](https://medium.com/swlh/kubernetes-configmap-confuguration-and-reload-strategy-9f8a286f3a44) and [this](https://github.com/fabric8io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/tree/master/spring-cloud-kubernetes-examples/kubernetes-reload-example) example to run spring boot applicaton in kube with reloading config map. When I set value everything is OK. But when I want set null or delete value from map then nothing happens

for example my init config map is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-app
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    config:
      testicek: stringvalue123
      inticek: 123
```

but when I change it to aand apply config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-app
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    config:
      testicek: null
      inticek: null
```

then testicek what is String contains empty string not null and inticek what is Integer was not even refreshed and still contain old value. Any tips how to fix this ?

**UPDATE**

so I found why null is solved as empty string [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19986). So after 4 years there is still no hook point how to change this behavior ? And even worse when I want to change Integer to null then nothing happens because, I guess, Integer can not be empty so setter of my property is not even called after configMap is changed

Comment: In your question you mention that "testicek what is String contains empty string not null and inticek what is Integer was not even refreshed and still contain old value". This relates to configmap or your spring boot application? Since after apply of changed configmap, `testicek` and `inticek` should be changed. Can you please add output for `kubectl describe configmap my-app` after changes applied?

Comment: yes, config map in kubectl got both property null but in my spring boot application inticek got still old value

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, the example that you are following is using `Deployment` and not vanilla `Pod`. This means you can do the rolling update of the new revision as following:

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment/minikube-sample
```

Comment: I can not restart application. I need to change config in runtime

Comment: I also add second example from spring

Answer (score 0):

You can auto-schedule the **Reload** of deployment using the Reloader.

The **reloader** will watch the configmap and secret.

Please checkout : https://github.com/stakater/Reloader

Comment: but it will restart my application ?

Comment: yes it will restart the stateful, deployment. check just document you will get idea.

Comment: ye abut as I said, I can not restart application